# Error in the run service

Tags: android

I have a mistake in my code. please help

Code

```
public void toCallAsynchronous() {
    Log.d(Tag, "проверка toCallAsynchronous");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                    //AutoPretraga zadatak = new AutoPretraga();
                                    //zadatak.execute();
                                        startService(
                                         new Intent(ctx, ServiceUpdate.class));
                                              Log.d(Tag, "ГУГЛ вперед!!!!!!!!");
                                              //googleConnect();



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(Tag, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 60000); // execute in every 2 second
}
```

Log

```
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:154)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at com.example.ok1.CopyOfMainActivity$1$1.run(CopyOfMainActivity.java:514)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-30 12:12:04.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in your CopyOfMainActivity.java line number 514 have issue, i think it is Log.d(Tag, e.getMessage()); line, just check if e.getMessage() is null or not

Comment: why the service does not start?

Comment: I add "Log.d(Tag, e.getMessage());" in comment

Comment: have u register service in manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is in line 514 in file CopyOfMainActivity.java, with call to Log.d method.
I am guessing it is this line

```
Log.d(Tag, "ГУГЛ вперед!!!!!!!!");
```

But as I look at this code I think You will have problem with all calls to Log methods because of "Tag".

Do You have a variable Tag of String type?
If Yes, then maybe Android have problem with these non Latin character but I doubt it.

try to edit all You log calls to for example:

```
Log.d("myservice", "ГУГЛ вперед!!!!!!!!");
```

Comment: Is it same error? because logcat says the problem is when calling Log.d method. If You comment it, do not call Log.d at all, the error can not be the same.